# ¿Qué significa el mensaje de error non-static method <nombre> cannot be referenced from a static context?

Tags: java

Tengo un código como sigue:

```
public class Clase {
    public void hazAlgo(String s) {
        /* implementación */
    }
}
```

Ahora estoy creando un método estático en `Clase` para validar que la cadena no contenga espacios a los costados. Si los tiene, los debe limpiar. Adicional a eso, debe utilizarse el método `hazAlgo`. Entonces, tengo el código así:

```
public class Clase {
    public void hazAlgo(String s) {
        /* implementación */
    }

    public static String limpiaCadena(String s) {
        s = (s == null) ? "" : s.trim();
        hazAlgo(s);
    }
}
```

Este código, al compilarlo, me manda el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
$ javac Clase.java 
Clase.java:8: error: non-static method hazAlgo(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
        hazAlgo(s);
        ^
1 error
```

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

El problema radica en comprender el significado de `static`. Los elementos (atributos o métodos) declarados como estáticos mediante el modificador `static` se pueden entender como elementos que le pertenecen a la clase y no a la instancia de la clase. En otras palabras, los elementos estáticos son globales para la clase que está cargada en memoria. Aquí un ejemplo de uso de un método estático:

```
public class UnaClase {
    public static void log(String mensaje) {
        System.out.println("[LOG] " + mensaje);
    }
    public void logNoEstatico(String mensaje) {
        System.out.println("[LOG no estatico] " + mensaje);
    }
}

public class ClasePrincipal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnaClase unaClase = new UnaClase();
        unaClase.log("hola mundo"); //llamando a método estático desde instancia, es válido
        UnaClase.log("hola mundo"); //llamando a método estático directamente desde la clase, es válido porque el método estático le "pertenece" a la clase y no a las instancias

        unaClase.logNoEstatico("hola mundo"); //llamando a método no estático desde instancia, es válido
        //UnaClase.logNoEstatico("hola mundo"); //no se puede llamar al método no estático directamente desde la clase, no es válido
    }
}
```

Como estos elementos pertenecen a la clase y no a la instancia, no se pueden utilizar elementos de la instancia para trabajar con elementos estáticos. ¿Qué significa esto? Que un atributo o método no estático **no se puede llamar** desde un método estático. Revisemos el método:

```
//el método limpiaCadena es estático, no necesita ninguna instancia
//de la clase para ser utilizado
public static String limpiaCadena(String s) {
    s = (s == null) ? "" : s.trim();
    //el método hazAlgo no es estático, entonces necesita
    //que se llame desde una instancia de la clase
    //como no existe una instancia aquí,
    //el compilador muestra el mensaje de error correspondiente
    hazAlgo(s);
}
```

---

¿Cómo resolver el problema?

La solución más simple es **no utilizar atributos ni métodos no estáticos directamente dentro de métodos estáticos**. Esto simplemente es un error. Si tienes una situación donde "necesitas" llamar a un atributo o método no estático dentro de un método estático, te voy adelantando que estás cometiendo un grave error de diseño. Advertencia puesta.

Una solución "sencilla" es cambiar el método no estático a estático, pero debes comprender el significado del cambio (si no entiendes el significado, vuelve a leer desde el inicio de la respuesta).

Existen alternativas a este problema:

1. Crea la instancia de la clase dentro del método estático:

   ```
   public static String limpiaCadena(String s) {
       s = (s == null) ? "" : s.trim();
       new Clase().hazAlgo(s);
   }
   ```

   Solo utiliza esto si es que la clase no mantiene estado. De todas formas, este es un diseño extraño y no recomendado.
2. Declara la clase como argumento del método estático:

   ```
   public static String limpiaCadena(String s, Clase instancia) {
       s = (s == null) ? "" : s.trim();
       instancia.hazAlgo(s);
   }
   ```

   Esta es una mejor alternativa, más limpia en diseño pero necesitarás más código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, yo tenia el mismo error y me fue muy util

Answer (score 0):

O simplemente llama al método de esta forma:

```
new Clase().hazAlgo();
```

Tomando tu código publicado, seria así:

```
public class Clase {
    public void hazAlgo(String s) {
        /* implementación */
    }

    public static String limpiaCadena(String s) {
        s = (s == null) ? "" : s.trim();
        new Clase().hazAlgo(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que agregaras un ejemplo de tu respuesta, para que sea mas facil de ayudar a quienes en un futuro busquen esta pregunta.

Comment: El método `hazalgo()` no esta implementado en el código de la pregunta. Sin IDE te puedo decir que eso no va compilar.

Comment: Esto ya es parte de la respuesta aceptada, que por cierto es mas antigua.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto también puede servir:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oKikiQtWVeFpkrhLrSceermh54-K14oSOYp29WLCHXc/edit?usp=sharing

Para ponerlo en código en vez de imágenes sería:

**Antes (con error)**

```
public class test {

    private volatile int establishedChangingTimeInterval;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        setTimeInterval(10);
        System.out.println(getTimeInterval());
    }

    public int getTimeInterval() {
        return establishedChangingTimeInterval;
    }

    private void setTimeInterval(int x) {
        establishedChangingTimeInterval = x;
    }

}
```

**Después (sin error):**

```
public class test {

    private volatile int establishedChangingTimeInterval;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //solution:
        test WeCanTakeItFromHere = new test();

        WeCanTakeItFromHere.setTimeInterval(10);
        System.out.println(WeCanTakeItFromHere.getTimeInterval());
    }

    public int getTimeInterval() {
        return establishedChangingTimeInterval;
    }

    private void setTimeInterval(int x) {
        establishedChangingTimeInterval = x;
    }

}
```