# Problema en Intent Android

Tags: java, android

Vereis cuando realizo este intent:

```
 case ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR: {
                DngCreator dngCreator = new DngCreator(mCharacteristics, mCaptureResult);
                FileOutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                    dngCreator.writeImage(output, mImage);
                    Intent i=new Intent(Camera2RawFragment.this,CameraVisorActivity.class);

                    success = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    mImage.close();
                    closeOutput(output);
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot save image, unexpected image format:" + format);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> "com.example.android.camera2raw.Camera2RawFragment" cannot be
>   referenced from a static context

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes mostrar más del contexto de tu código? Me entra la sospecha que haces algo equivocado en el contexto de Android en general. Normalmente no necesitas usar **nada** estático en aplicaciones Android. En que método/clase usas el código que compartiste?

Comment: Mira esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14746/29967 Es posible que estés intentando llamar un atributo o método no estático desde un  método estático.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer intentas abrir un `Intent` usando el `Fragment` como contexto, en este caso `Camera2RawFragment`.

Al abrir una `Activity` desde un `Fragment` debes usar como contexto la `Activity` que contiene al `Fragment`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),CameraVisorActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

---

**Abrir Activity desde Fragment:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Abrir Activity desde Activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NuevaActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

o tambièn

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityActual.this, NuevaActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```